# Go template is adding extra quotes to output

Tags: go-templates

I want to use the value of my variable in Go template as-is but Go is adding extra quotes around it. E.g., for a Go template like

`{{.Site}}:{{.Port}}/{{.Path}}`

I want to get the output as

`Mysite:3000/from/here`

but the template is giving me the following instead:

`"Mysite":"3000"/"from/here"`

So,

- How can I fix it (get rid of all the extra quotes or better suspend them all)? See https://play.golang.org/p/uKpgXdLv5gM
- Go template also changed `"orgId=1&refresh=30s"` to `orgId=1\u0026refresh=30s`, how to avoid that?
- Moreover, if I add `https://` to the front of my url, the output is truncated. How to fix that as well?
- Finally, is it possible to escape "`" within "`"?

Comment: Have you tried using regular `"`? https://play.golang.org/p/D1uUcOHuQZu The html/template package sanitizes the data to avoid injection. The [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) contain a lot more details about what it does.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, I need "\`" because of the `${othervars}` in JS. I only show one, but I have many in the JS string building.

Comment: The docs might tell you how, I haven't checked. The extreme solution would be to use the text/template package, but it won't sanitize anything.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS ?

Comment: or use a concat function.

Comment: or just expose a variable with the desired string.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/SzuBKDVBhCz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Go HTML template doc](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#hdr-Introduction):

> HTML templates treat data values as plain text which should be encoded so they can be safely embedded in an HTML document. The escaping is contextual, so actions can appear within JavaScript, CSS, and URI contexts.
>
> The security model used by this package assumes that template authors are trusted, while Execute's data parameter is not. More details are provided below.

It means JavaScript escaping is enabled whenever the go HTML template engine detects that it is within a `<script>` tag, (i.e., it has nothing to do with whether using regular `"` or not as the first commenter thinks). So

to get the output as

`Mysite:3000/from/here`

instead of:

`"Mysite":"3000"/"from/here"`

Do ***not*** wrap it with `<script>` & `</script>` tag.
Do the concatenation *after* template `Execute()`.

Again, with `<script>` & `</script>` tag wrapped around, I'm getting:

```
var url = `"Mysite":"3000"/"from/here"/${othervars}?"orgId=1\u0026refresh=30s"`
```

vs. without `<script>` & `</script>` tag wrapped around it, I'm getting:

```
var url = `Mysite:3000/from/here/${othervars}?orgId=1&amp;refresh=30s`
```

Just what I need.

However, my actual case is that I'm using go HTML template engine to process my .html template files, so I cannot really do the concatenation afterwards, as everything is defined in the .html template file. So, just as Martin Gallagher has shown in his code, for such case, using template function seems to be the only option.

But even that might not be a viable option, as this is what I'm getting out of Martin's code:

`var url = "Mysite:3000\/from\/here?orgId=1\u0026refresh=30s"`

It is still not exactly what I wanted:

```
var url = `Mysite:3000/from/here/${othervars}?orgId=1&amp;refresh=30s`
```

So maybe with such case, it indeed has no ideal solution.